# multiple classes on "document.querySelector "

Tags: javascript, css

Please help, I still learn about JS.

How to add multiple class when I've situation like this?
I've two trigger .m-trigger and d-trigger

```
var ModalEffects = (function() {

function init() {

    var overlay = document.querySelector( '.md-overlay' );

    [].slice.call( document.querySelectorAll( '.d-trigger' ) ).forEach( function( el, i ) {

        var modal = document.querySelector( '#' + el.getAttribute( 'data-modal' ) ),
            close = modal.querySelector( '.md-close' );

        function removeModal( hasPerspective ) {
            classie.remove( modal, 'md-show' );

            if( hasPerspective ) {
                classie.remove( document.documentElement, 'md-perspective' );
            }
        }

        function removeModalHandler() {
            removeModal( classie.has( el, 'md-setperspective' ) ); 
        }

        el.addEventListener( 'click', function( ev ) {
            classie.add( modal, 'md-show' );
            overlay.removeEventListener( 'click', removeModalHandler );
            overlay.addEventListener( 'click', removeModalHandler );

            if( classie.has( el, 'md-setperspective' ) ) {
                setTimeout( function() {
                    classie.add( document.documentElement, 'md-perspective' );
                }, 25 );
            }
        });

        close.addEventListener( 'click', function( ev ) {
            ev.stopPropagation();
            removeModalHandler();
        });

    } );

}

init();
```

I tried to add like this

```
document.querySelectorAll( '.d-trigger.m-trigger' )
```

and

```
document.querySelectorAll( '.d-trigger' '.m-trigger' )
```

the modal doesn't work correctly, the first code make any trigger doesn't work, and the second code only work on first class.

I've solution for this, just copy all code and change the class. but any solution for this?

Comment: use a comma seperated list, ie `'.d-trigger, .m-trigger'`. Note `'.d-trigger.m-trigger'` would try to select elements that has both classes instead of selecting elements that have either class

Comment: hi, thank you for your reply.

I've tried that '.d-trigger, .m-trigger'

the result is just work on .m-trigger . the .d-trigger not work

Comment: What tutorial did you use? Because `[].slice.call( document.querySelectorAll( '.d-trigger' ) ).forEach` is ridiculous: querySelectorAll() returns a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList), which [already has forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach). Also, don't use string concatenation with `'...' _+ ...`, use templating strings: that's what they're for. If you must: ```querySelector(`#${element...}`)``` but if you're selecting on `id`, _there is a function for this already_ and it's `document.getElementById()`.